# Как удалить спам из visual composer?

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

Скачал visual composer и только сейчас заметил что в сафари и фаерфокс появлются скрытые теги с линками в теле статьи, но в хроме тело статьи нормальное, кто сталкивался с таким? как это вырезать? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что "скачал". А чтобы без ссылок и вирусов -  надо было купить. А лучше вообще выкинуть эту хрень и делать сайт нормально.

Comment: @SeVlad , да уж, купил, так проще, ну чего хрень ))) можно кастомные модули делать, очень помогает. https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=524332

Comment: Потому что это чудо (как и другие виз конструкторы) ломает понимание работы с ВП, и генерит туёву хучу проблем.  Они не помогают, а мешают. Зло это - пейдбилдеры. Большое зло.

Comment: @SeVlad вероятно вы правы, не буду спорить, я еще в вп-то толком не вкурил, сижу велосипеды кручу. Во всяком случае спасибо за инфу.

Comment: Начинать разбираться надо с правильных методов. а не этих костылей для домохозяек. Да даже не костылей а...медвежья услуга эти пейджбилдеры. Повторю - без них многое сделать проще, а результат на порядок лучше. Во время разработки лучше поставь [QM](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) (или другой мониторинг) - увидишь проблемные места.